# Запаздывающие генераторы Фибоначчи (subtract_with_carry_engine)

Tags: c++, случайные-числа

Дали мне задание написать написать генератор случайных чисел методом фибоначчи с запаздыванием.
Я нашёл, что `subtract_with_carry_engine` как раз то что мне нужно. Но я не могу понять, как он работает! Т.е. в теории, почитав википедию(и мою методичку), метод вроде бы понятен, но не понятно как работает именно `subtract_with_carry_engine`! Как его использовать для получения:

1. чисел из определённого диапазона
2. как задать период генератора

```
#include <iostream>

#include <random>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int E, R;

    cin >> E;
    cin >> R;

    subtract_with_carry_engine<unsigned, 24, 51, 110> g1(E);


    subtract_with_carry_engine<unsigned, 13, 51, 100> g2(R); 


    cout << "Your seed produced: " << g1() << endl;
    cout << "Your seed produced: " << g2() << endl;


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Я не понимаю как изменяются получаемые числа, если например я меняю "`unsigned, 13, 51, 100`", на "`unsigned, 16, 40, 70`".

Comment: В задании точно написано _задать_ период генератора, а не вычислить его по параметрам?

Comment: @Chorkov Я прочёл на вики, что мы можем задать его. Там сказано "...причём период генератора должен быть более или равен (2^m) - 1". Я воспринял это как то, что период можно задать

Comment: В википедии, имелось ввиду, что период должен удовлетворять данному условию, чтобы вычисляемую по формуле последовательность, вообще можно было считать псевдослучайной. Понятно, что не для всякого набора параметров это условие выполняется. Советую брать один из рекомендованных наборов параметров (несколько пар рекомендованных значений можно найти там же в вики). Длинна периода для большинства рекомендованных пар проверена экспериментально (численно).

Comment: @Chorkov я конечно могу просто скопировать эти параметры, но от этого я не пойму как изменяются получаемые числа после изменения параметров. А я хочу понять.

Comment: По теме есть ещё такая информация, [http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/subtract_with_carry_engine/subtract_with_carry_engine/]
но сильно понятнее от неё не становится. Мертвая тема эти аддитивные генераторы :(